# What are these pests that are eating my pomegranate roots, and how can I control them?

Tags: identification, pest-control, pests, pest-damage, pesticide

I'm not sure what pest this is, but it is eating the roots of my pomegranate shrub. I saw it once on the top soil, and, when digging into the soil, I unearthed around 15 of these pests. I need to know what this is, so that I can apply the proper pest control.

I live in the Philippines, and a friend of mine said that it is common in their place, and loves to eat rhizomes and members of the potato family. She said that in their province, they call it "batag." Another friend said they call it "cutter" since it cuts the roots of the plant and sometimes the stems. Another said that it is "ulalo." I'm really confused, so any identification would really help. Here are the pictures:

[image: Picture 1] [image: Picture 2]

Comment: It didn't show familiar to me, but searching for `ulalo` showed me a picture of the same animal on [this page](http://www.infonet-biovision.org/default/ct/121/), on which the picture is captioned *"Whitegrubs, Chafer grub (Schyzonycha spp.)"*, which is the [larva of a scarab](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/field/white_grub.htm). Maybe that's helpful?

Comment: Thanks! Now I know! I'll do what I can to control them! ^^

Comment: The thumb in the second photo provides a useful, if troubling, sense of scale.

Answer (score 1):

Those appear to be white grubs, [*Leucopholis irrorata*](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233581563_White_Grub_Leucopholis_irrorata_(Coleoptera_Scarabaeidae)_Pest_Status_Population_Dynamics_and_Chemical_Control_in_a_Rice-Maize_Cropping_Pattern_in_the_Philippines). It's a common pest in your area. A [trichlorfon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrifonate)  or [carbaryl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbaryl) based insecticide should control them easily.